# Path Integral Simulation

Tags: simulations, path-integral

I am trying to do a simulation with path integrals. I previously simulated with a step potential by time evolving the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian. See [code and video](http://acsweb.ucsd.edu/~amacdona/notes/Physics/Quantum/). Notice is is a bit weird, spreads out really fast, because I set $ \hbar = 1 $. If this simulation is wrong, please let me know too, but I am pretty sure it is right.

Now, I am trying to follow these notes for a class I almost took, but couldn't for lack of time. [Everything](http://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/spring2015/physics142/Labs/Lab3/Lab3.html) but see the "Feynman Path Integral in Practice (PDF Document)" link for the notes. FORTRAN code at the bottom.

## Math Reasoning

So my mathematical reasoning is as follows

$$
\langle x_f, t_f | x_i, t_i \rangle = \int \mathit{D}x \exp\left[ i \int\limits_{t_i}^{t_f} dt L(x, \dot{x}) \right] \\
\approx \sum_{Dx} \prod_t \exp\left[i \Delta t\ L(\frac{x_t + x_{t+1}}{\Delta t}, \frac{x_{t+1} - x_t}{\Delta t})\right] \Delta x^n \\
= \sum_{x_1} ... \sum_{x_n} U(x_1, x_2) ... U(x_{n-1}, x_n)
$$

With,
$$
U(x_t, x_{t+1}) = \Delta x \exp\left[i \Delta t\ L(\frac{x_t + x_{t+1}}{2}, \frac{x_{t+1} - x_t}{\Delta t})\right]
$$

We can see that our approximate path integral turns into a matrix multiplication,

$$
\langle x_f, t_f | x_i, t_i \rangle \approx \mathbf{U}^n
$$
for $ n $ discrete time step approximations.

I figured then I could take $ \mathbf{U}^{m} $ for $ m < n $ as a small time propagator approximation and simulate in time by plotting,

$$
 \langle x | U^{m k} | \psi \rangle
$$
for discrete steps $ k $

## My wavefunction and potential

I am using a gaussian wavefunction with a right moving momentum as in the other simulation because I want to compare.

My step potential is +3 at the origin.

My simulation is coming out really weird. I have no clue why. Could you please explain what I am doing wrong? I am more confident in my programming abilities than my math, but [here](http://acsweb.ucsd.edu/~amacdona/notes/Physics/Quantum/one-side-step-path.py) is my code.

Comment: Did you try a free particle and a particle in a box? I think it's important to test your code with examples that have exact solutions and you need to characterize numerical errors on those examples before moving on to potentials that don't have simple, intuitively easy to understand solutions.

Comment: Yes, I did the free particle (ie just set the step to zero) and I did it with zero momentum too. When I do either, I get a weird pdf that looks like a bunch of repeated wobbling gaussians. I was concerned that what I am doing isn't causing the phase noise to cancel. I picked this potential because it is pretty easy (reflection transmission, etc).

Comment: My concern was if I was doing my math poorly, something which would take a really long time to debug

Comment: If the free particle doesn't come out correctly (you know the exact solution), then your code is either not correct or the method is numerically unstable (my hunch is that the free particle gaussian is about as well-behaved numerically as functions come, after all, it's in $C_\infty$). You can't make this work without being able to understand the properties of the free particle solution. OTOH, they should be in nearly every beginners' textbook on QM.

Comment: So the propagator as listed in "Principles of Quantum Mechanics" by Shankar and "Geometry, Topology, and Physics" by Nakahara is $ \exp\left( \frac{im (x_f - x_t)^2}{2T} \right) $. Which is exactly what I have as my matrix for $ T = \Delta t $. I'll keep hacking around to see if I can figure out the numerical stability problem. I have a feeling it is the complex numbers ... I always hate computing them.

Comment: That the calculations use complex numbers won't produce any stability problems all by itself and there are trivial real valued problems that have extreme convergence problems. Did you read the literature about numerical solutions to the Schroedinger equation?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean stability in a numeric sense, but the way complex number are handled in Python, depending on various operators, something like $ 5 + 0i $ and $ 5 - 0i $ have large phase shifts and mess things up (experience). But I haven't read about the numerical solutions. Could you point me to something good? I am taking a seminar on Numerical PDE solutions starting in 10 days.

Comment: I see. I have not heard about problems with complex numbers in Python, but the scipy libraries shouldn't have these problems, they are based on highly debugged numerical libraries (or so I thought...), so if you pick representations that can feed the standard numerics libs, then you should be fine, as long as the algorithms are stable. As for the numerics... talk to the lecturer, he/she should be able to point you to the newest literature.

Comment: I emailed one of the professors at my university. I found his Fortran code that does this for a harmonic oscillator. I noticed that he uses sine and cosine to compute his complex exponential. It turns out that it works if I formulate this way. My code is linked below. You will notice that there is a commented out version for the K matrix and the active one. They "should" be equivalent, but I think the complex numbers are messing things up. http://acsweb.ucsd.edu/~amacdona/notes/Physics/Quantum/harmonic-path-integ.py Can you help be understand what is going on? I think sqrt is phase shifting